# Trying to prevent Yup form validation from accepting -0 as a positive integer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, yup

I’m creating a form validation with Yup in a react project. I want a min number of 0 and a max number of 10 (simple enough right?) Problem is for some reason -0 is allowed as a valid positive integer. Any suggestions on implementing something to prevent this and only allowing 0-10 would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This is what I have so far and I cant seem to find a method in Yup's documentation to resolve this. forgive me if this is too vague

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  weight: Yup.number()
    .required(`Value required`)
    .integer()
    .positive()
    .min(0)
    .max(10, `Weight can't be greater than 10`),
});
```

I am getting the result I want as far as validation.. BUT -0 seems to be acceptable which I can't have.

Thanks again

Comment: Could you update your question and include what you've tried so far?

Comment: **0 does't have a sign by definition. try casting to int.** Also, In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)